# Undefined Kernel Panic on macOS 10.15.5

Tags: macos, catalina, kernel-panic, kernel

I encountered an undefined kernel panic on MacOs Catalina 10.5.5. When panic occurs, the screen goes black suddenly and tihs page appeared:

[image]

After, Mac restarts itself. I got the panic logs:

**Log 1:**

```
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff8013178738): "a freed zone element has been modified in zone kalloc.128: expected 0xdeadbeefdeadbeef but found 0xffffff80476b46d0, bits changed 0x2152416f99c6f83f, at offset 88 of 128 in element 0xffffff803403a500, cookies 0x3f0011cad0bf5d7a 0x53521051abf01c7"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-6153.121.2/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:1229
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9203c1b860 : 0xffffff801311f5cd 
0xffffff9203c1b8b0 : 0xffffff8013258b05 
0xffffff9203c1b8f0 : 0xffffff801324a68e 
0xffffff9203c1b940 : 0xffffff80130c5a40 
0xffffff9203c1b960 : 0xffffff801311ec97 
0xffffff9203c1ba60 : 0xffffff801311f087 
0xffffff9203c1bab0 : 0xffffff80138c27cc 
0xffffff9203c1bb20 : 0xffffff8013178738 
0xffffff9203c1bb50 : 0xffffff8013178fd6 
0xffffff9203c1bb70 : 0xffffff801317a608 
0xffffff9203c1bbb0 : 0xffffff8013176a57 
0xffffff9203c1bce0 : 0xffffff801312c4b4 
0xffffff9203c1bd50 : 0xffffff801315c710 
0xffffff9203c1bdc0 : 0xffffff801315ce29 
0xffffff9203c1be10 : 0xffffff801362457a 
0xffffff9203c1be50 : 0xffffff8013623bdc 
0xffffff9203c1beb0 : 0xffffff801362934b 
0xffffff9203c1bf40 : 0xffffff8013787097 
0xffffff9203c1bfa0 : 0xffffff80130c6206 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: UserEventAgent

Mac OS version:
19F101

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Tue May 26 20:41:44 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.121.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 54F1A78D-6F41-32BD-BFED-4381F9F6E2EF
Kernel slide:     0x0000000012e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8013000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8012f00000
System model name: iMac14,3 (Mac-77EB7D7DAF985301)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 35856113398232
last loaded kext at 195626405894: com.vmware.kext.vmx86 1626.94.56 (addr 0xffffff7f9712c000, size 86016)
last unloaded kext at 709807690252: >!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60 (addr 0xffffff7f9694b000, size 45056)
loaded kexts:
com.vmware.kext.vmx86   1626.94.56
com.vmware.kext.vmnet   1626.94.56
com.symantec.ips.kext   9.0.2
com.symantec.nfm.kext   9.0.1
com.symantec.internetSecurity.kext  9.0.3
com.symantec.SymXIPS    9.0.1
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4.3
>!A!BMultitouch 97
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@fileutil   20.036.15
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AMikeyHIDDriver   131
>!AMikeyDriver  283.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.4
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.5f6
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
@GeForce    14.0.0
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IHD5000Graphics 14.0.6
>eficheck   1
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!ALPC  3.1
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!A!IFramebufferAzul    14.0.6
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.120.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
>!ASDXC 1.7.7
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!AAHCIPort 341.0.2
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!A!BHIDKeyboard    209
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.5f6
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
@kext.triggers  1.0
|IOAVB!F    850.1
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.3
@nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal 14.0.0
@nvidia.driver.NVDAResman   14.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.4
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.4
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.5.4
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
|IOHDA!F    283.15
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.5f6
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.5f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.5f6
|IO!B!F 7.0.5f6
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.5f6
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOSurface  269.11
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.100.5
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.121.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

**Log 2:**

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800324aa3a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f845b7fb8, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffffc0352aec1e, CR3: 0x00000000294ab173, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0xffffff80352b0c00, RBX: 0x00000000ffffff80, RCX: 0x0000003fffffe000, RDX: 0x0000000002ee09a0
RSP: 0xffffff920affb700, RBP: 0xffffff920affb740, RSI: 0xffffff802862c150, RDI: 0x0000000000000001
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x0000000000000002, R10: 0x0000000000000001, R11: 0x0000000000000041
R12: 0xffffff80566b7358, R13: 0xffffff802df43d10, R14: 0xffffff8023ce6a10, R15: 0xffffff802862c000
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff7f845b7fb8, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffffc0352aec1e, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0, VF: 1

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff920affb160 : 0xffffff800311f5cd 
0xffffff920affb1b0 : 0xffffff8003258b05 
0xffffff920affb1f0 : 0xffffff800324a68e 
0xffffff920affb240 : 0xffffff80030c5a40 
0xffffff920affb260 : 0xffffff800311ec97 
0xffffff920affb360 : 0xffffff800311f087 
0xffffff920affb3b0 : 0xffffff80038c27cc 
0xffffff920affb420 : 0xffffff800324aa3a 
0xffffff920affb5a0 : 0xffffff800324a738 
0xffffff920affb5f0 : 0xffffff80030c5a40 
0xffffff920affb610 : 0xffffff7f845b7fb8 
0xffffff920affb740 : 0xffffff7f845b699a 
0xffffff920affb7f0 : 0xffffff7f8458d00b 
0xffffff920affb890 : 0xffffff7f8458e467 
0xffffff920affb920 : 0xffffff7f8458ecce 
0xffffff920affb980 : 0xffffff7f844a3a4f 
0xffffff920affb9b0 : 0xffffff7f844b267d 
0xffffff920affb9f0 : 0xffffff7f8458e9b2 
0xffffff920affba40 : 0xffffff7f844a100b 
0xffffff920affbac0 : 0xffffff800385695e 
0xffffff920affbb10 : 0xffffff8003854be7 
0xffffff920affbb60 : 0xffffff800385dcb3 
0xffffff920affbca0 : 0xffffff80032082b2 
0xffffff920affbdb0 : 0xffffff8003125328 
0xffffff920affbe10 : 0xffffff80030fbcc5 
0xffffff920affbe70 : 0xffffff8003112aa2 
0xffffff920affbf00 : 0xffffff8003230d05 
0xffffff920affbfa0 : 0xffffff80030c6226 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.5.4)[D695D9DA-7C20-35D6-910F-E7A332A0F515]@0xffffff7f8449a000->0xffffff7f8455efff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[E35D090D-DB9E-3DD0-9723-651FA730AA13]@0xffffff7f8446c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BE052F4D-9B80-3FCD-B36D-BACB7DEE0DF2]@0xffffff7f83b31000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.11)[F1E7389D-2807-3C5D-8A7F-5422542E867F]@0xffffff7f83fe9000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(576.1)[B1C0006F-E1F5-37D9-9548-5F918E92B422]@0xffffff7f8401b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[1FB49168-0280-3F04-A99A-F830C915E994]@0xffffff7f84493000
         com.apple.GeForce(14.0)[BF59B26E-F3C1-3B72-B731-1E4E5F506524]@0xffffff7f84573000->0xffffff7f8460efff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BE052F4D-9B80-3FCD-B36D-BACB7DEE0DF2]@0xffffff7f83b31000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.11)[F1E7389D-2807-3C5D-8A7F-5422542E867F]@0xffffff7f83fe9000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(576.1)[946300BB-3488-3655-B4A3-2263D72C525C]@0xffffff7f8407a000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(14.0.0)[ECB33CB3-2FE3-3E99-A4E6-ED7C5DA6D543]@0xffffff7f84096000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(576.1)[B1C0006F-E1F5-37D9-9548-5F918E92B422]@0xffffff7f8401b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.5.4)[D695D9DA-7C20-35D6-910F-E7A332A0F515]@0xffffff7f8449a000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Microsoft Edge H

Mac OS version:
19F101

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Tue May 26 20:41:44 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.121.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 54F1A78D-6F41-32BD-BFED-4381F9F6E2EF
Kernel slide:     0x0000000002e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8003000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8002f00000
System model name: iMac14,3 (Mac-77EB7D7DAF985301)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 36706647814307
last loaded kext at 33002521825589: >!AXsanScheme   3 (addr 0xffffff7f8713f000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 4427079080436: >usb.!UHostPacketFilter    1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f84f11000, size 24576)
loaded kexts:
com.vmware.kext.vmx86   1626.94.56
com.vmware.kext.vmnet   1626.94.56
com.symantec.ips.kext   9.0.2
com.symantec.nfm.kext   9.0.1
com.symantec.internetSecurity.kext  9.0.3
com.symantec.SymXIPS    9.0.1
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4.3
>!A!BMultitouch 97
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   111.4.4
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AMikeyHIDDriver   131
>!AMikeyDriver  283.15
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.4
>!ASMCLMU   212
@GeForce    14.0.0
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.5f6
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IHD5000Graphics 14.0.6
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>eficheck   1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!A!IFramebufferAzul    14.0.6
>!ALPC  3.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.120.2
>!ASDXC 1.7.7
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AAHCIPort 341.0.2
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!A!BHIDKeyboard    209
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.5f6
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal 14.0.0
@nvidia.driver.NVDAResman   14.0.0
|IOAVB!F    850.1
>!ASSE  1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.4
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.3
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.4
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.5.4
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
|IOHDA!F    283.15
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.5f6
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.5f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.5f6
|IO!B!F 7.0.5f6
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.5f6
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOSurface  269.11
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.100.5
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.121.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

I cannot catch what app or service happen it. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I am getting the same issue but without the restart window, mine just shuts off.... same log as well.

Comment: You’ve got a lot of 3rd party kexts loaded like things for MS Edge and VMware. You might want to start with booting into Safe Mode to see if the issues go away. Also, try a different (new) user account to see if the issues are contained to your user space. Give those a shot and post your results

Comment: @Allan no its not. Its an ongoing issue with catalina 10.15.4 and 10.15.5 - https://www.macrumors.com/2020/04/06/macos-10-5-4-kernel-panic-crashing-issues/

Comment: @whiraj Kernel panics have happened in virtually every release of macOS for one reason or another.  That article specifically identifies *large file transfers* which isn't mentioned anywhere by the OP.  That's a rather large leap you made there as to causation.  Secondly, anecdotal reports of crashing via Twitter is definitely not something you want to rely on as credible.  How about we *try* some diagnostics?